# Will R on Cygwin display graphics if it runs in a Cygwin/X terminal?

Tags: r, cygwin

R on Cygwin writes plots to Rplots.pdf. I'd like to be able to display them instead. I have not installed Cygwin/X. If I do it and run R from a Cygwin/X terminal, will R be able to display graphics to the screen? If so, will this be automatic or are some special commands needed? Thank you.

Comment: Cygwin is not a supported R environment, so you may have to try and see what works. Even if you could find a hack to make it work, there's no telling what other command will break, so it's not a sustainable solution.

Answer (score 2):

It can plot on the go as long as you have Cygwin/X packages installed, and open an X11 window (by the command `startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1 &`) before you start R session in the same console. However as @ilir mentioned, Cygwin is not officially supported by R ([R Installation and Administration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Cygwin)), it has to be used with care.